# iochanging slid-in and slid-out animation to fade-in and fade-out in SWRevealViewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using `SWRevealViewController` for menu on the left, I want to change the default animation and make Fade-Out animation. I tried with the delegate they have as below but it didn't work out.

```
    func revealController(_ revealController: SWRevealViewController!, animateTo position: FrontViewPosition) {
    if position == .left {
        view.alpha = 0.15
    }
    else if position == .right {
        view.alpha = 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    func fadeIn(_ duration: TimeInterval = 1.0, delay: TimeInterval = 0.0, completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void) = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.alpha = 1.0
            }, completion: completion)  }

    func fadeOut(_ duration: TimeInterval = 1.0, delay: TimeInterval = 0.0, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0.15
            }, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Now in change your function like this

```
func revealController(_ revealController: SWRevealViewController!, animateTo position: FrontViewPosition) {
    if position == .left {
        view.fadeOut()
    }
    else if position == .right {
        view.fadeIn()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.ebc.cat/2015/03/07/customize-your-swrevealviewcontroller-slide-out-menu/)!

Or you could try this

```
revealViewController.toggleAnimationType = SWRevealToggleAnimationTypeEaseOut
```